# Why does Java convert byte and short operands to ints during numeric promotion

Tags: java, jls

What are the reasons behind the extension of small datatypes (e.g. byte) to int during the [Numeric Promotion](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/conversions.html#5.6) process? Wouldn't it be possible to perform most of the operations directly on these smaller datatypes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The VM is a virtual machine, the JIT translates this to native code and optimises it then.  All registers are either 32-bit or 64-bit and "shorter" operations are not necessarily and faster.

Answer (score 0):

The VM does not support integers smaller than 4 octets, so when running in the VM you are operating on 4 octet ints or 8 octet longs. (Well it does for arrays, barray sarray, etc, just not for single values).